# Why does URLSession return null instead of json data as the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, swiftui

I have this code that sends a username and password to a local API (it's http at the moment since I'm developing it still and it's not on a server yet). However the data returned is just the response code, instead of the body of the response which is meant to contain an auth-token.

This is the Client-code (my app in SwiftUI):

```
func login(username:String, password:String){
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/users/login") else { print("URL error"); return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
    let headers = [
        //"auth-token": "auth-token goes here",
        "accept": "string",
        "content-type": "application/json"]
    let body = [
        "username": username,
        "password": password]
    do{
    let dataToSend = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        request.httpBody = dataToSend
    }catch{
        print("Error creating data object")
        return
    }
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        // Check for erros
        if error == nil && data != nil{
            // Try parse out data
            print(data)
            do {
                let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                print(dictionary)
            }
            catch{
                print("Error parsing response data")
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

When I print out the data response before I try and put it in a dictionary I get this:
`Optional(200 bytes)`

I get the response code instead of the body of the response (which is json), why?

This is my server-side code:

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {

    // Validate before we login user
    const { error } = loginValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    // Checking if the user exists
    const user = await User.findOne({username: req.body.username});
    if(!user) return res.status(400).send("Invalid username")

    // Check if password is correct
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send("Invalid password")

    console.log(req.body);
    // User is logged in provide them with a token
    const token = jwt.sign({
        _id: user._id,
        _username: user.username
    }, "SECRET_KEY", { expiresIn: '1h' });
    res.status(200).header('auth-token', token).send(token);
});
```

Comment: It's the data's count mate, not response status code. What are you getting from `print(dictionary)`?

Comment: @Frankenstein Mistyped oops, let me change that. I printed both, the data and the dictionary, data itself returns 200bytes and I cannot print the print(dictionary as an error occurs when I try to `JSONSerialization` the data into the dictionary...

Comment: It means the you're not receiving a json response. try `print(String(decoding: data! as: UTF*.self))`, let me know what you got.

Comment: @Frankenstein sorry, I've just gotten back into Swift after a two year break and I'm trying the new SwiftUI, so I'm a little rusty, I tried putting in that line of code to get the output you wanted but I got an error `Expected type after 'as'` and not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data doesn't seem to contain a valid `JSON`, it's the reason your code doesn't print out the `dictionary` that you tried to parse out. Here's how you find the response data:

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
        print(dictionary)
    } catch {
        print("Error parsing response data: \(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))")

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, great so the line `print("Error parsing response data: \(String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self))")` actually prints out `Error parsing response data + auth-token` which is what I expected to be returned! So it was another massive silly mistake on my part...needed fresh pair of eyes I guess, thank you!